# SWFObject (1.5 and 2.1) does not allow full-screen in IE

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, swfobject

Does anybody know why and/or how to work around this without scraping SWFObject?

Many thanks,
T

EDIT : Sorry, my fault the alowFullScreen param was set to "**true**" instead of "**always**"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have the `allowFullscreen` Flashvar set in the containing HTML? See this [tutorial](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=05B_Security_06.html) for details (including Full Screen mode security details).

Comment: Yup sure thing it's in ... it's only in IE the problem happens.

Comment: The fullScreen feature is buggy: Search the Adobe Bug base if this is not what you are facing (Vista/IE7 issue) <https://bugs.adobe.com/jira/browse/FP-395>.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, my fault the allowFullScreen param was set to "true" instead of "always"